# Removing dictionary from value as list in dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to remove a dictionary from list of dictionaries as value.

```
d = {"monitors": [{"name": "monitor1", "ip": "0.0.0.0"},
                  {"name": "monitor2", "ip": "1.1.1.1"}]}

for value in d["monitors"]:
  if value["name"] == "monitor1":
    # delete {"name": "monitor1", "ip": "0.0.0.0"}

print(d)
```

result must to be: {'monitors': [{'name': 'monitor2', 'ip': '1.1.1.1'}]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using list comprehension:

```
d = {"monitors": [{"name": "monitor1", "ip": "0.0.0.0"},
                  {"name": "monitor2", "ip": "1.1.1.1"}]}

d['monitors'] = [i for i in d['monitors'] if i['name'] != 'monitor1']

print(d)
```

Prints:

```
{'monitors': [{'ip': '1.1.1.1', 'name': 'monitor2'}]}
```

Comment: @r_junior Yes, the value `{"name": "monitor1", "ip": "0.0.0.0"}` is removed from dictionary `d`

Comment: Oh yeah! Thank you very much!